# Смена языка сообщения error_code в boost

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, boost, локализация

Когда я получаю ошибку в бусте, я могу ее прочитать, вызвав метод  `error_code::message()`. Я бы хотел, чтобы она выводилась на английском (сейчас она выводится на русском).

Вот пример кода:

```
// boost_client_test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/asio.hpp>  
#include <boost/bind.hpp>  

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class client
{
public:
    client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
        const std::string& server) : socket_(io_service), 
        ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 22304)
    {
        socket_.async_connect(ep,
            boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

private:
    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            /*some code*/
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n"; // выводит здесь сообщение об ошибке (на русском)
        }
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    tcp::endpoint ep;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); //с локалью сообщение об ошибке выводится на русском, без нее (или с ней, но вместо "rus" стоит "eng") - кракозябры
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        client c(io_service, "127.0.0.1");
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Запускал код в Windows 7 в Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, версия буста 1.59.0.
Язык системы - русский, но смена его на английский лишь превратила выводимые символы в кракозябры :(
Как поменять язык выводимой ошибки?

Comment: Скорее всего нужно просто установить англоязычную VS.

Comment: @alexout у меня англоязычная VS.

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос версии используемых программ и [mcve], чтобы можно было повторить проблему.

Comment: @alexout добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моём случае помогла установка языка пользовательского интерфейса для текущего потока выполнения [`SetThreadUILanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374053(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
SetThreadUILanguage(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US));
```

После этого сообщение вывелось на английском:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Спасибо, работает! А можно такое сделать непосредственно в бусте? Хотелось бы иметь кроссплатформенное решение.

Comment: @OlegYablokov можно поискать по исходникам. Но я не уверен, что оно есть. Вряд ли все поддерживаемые ОС буста содержат тексты ошибок на всех языках мира.